# Which algorithm or program or code has a very bad usage of cache

Tags: c, algorithm, caching

I am currently doing a little bit of research and I was looking for examples of algorithms that have very bad utilization of cache in all aspects(in spatial and temporal locality). One example I know is accessing columns first rather than rows in a nested loop in a row major accessing compiler but this is not that bad as well . Is there something that is way worse than this? Any help would be useful

Comment: Computing the values of non-linear recurrences, like [Hofstadter's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence), has both. The reason is that to compute a new term, the recurrence requires values of far or nearby previous terms, chaotically. More artificially you could just require looking for terms getting far apart and with many repetitions: A[1], A[2], A[1],A[3], A[2], A[1], A[4], A[3], A[2], A[1], A[5], A[4], A[3], A[2], A[1],...

Comment: @conditionalMethod but will this not use temporal locality as we are accessing the same data again and again. Therefore the caches will have good hit

Comment: Well, temporal locality is not only about a reference being used many times, but also that those times are not too far apart. Take a look at A[1] in the last example. It is accessed many times, but those times are getting farther and farther apart with many other references needed in between. Eventually the cache storing A[1] will need to be used for some other A[k] even thought A[1] will still be requested many times in the future.